# Solve the improper integral: $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{33e^{-\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm completely stuck on this one. I only know that it converges thanks to Wolfram, but I don't know how to evaluate it.

$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{33e^{-\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Did you mean $\int_1^\infty e^{-\sqrt{x}}/\sqrt{x}\,dx$?

Comment: Let $u={\sqrt x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. If you make the change of variable
$$
u=\sqrt{x},\quad du=\frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}},
$$ then 
$$
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{33e^{-\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}\:dx=66\int_1^{\infty}e^{-u}\:du.
$$

Comment: I didn't see that. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielWaleniak You are welcome.